# How to display in between records in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

i have a table which contains events from an access control system.
I want to show First In and Last out of the employee per day(working hour 8:00 to 5:00),in addition to this

i want last out and Last in  for the lunch break(in between 12:45 & 2:15) for that day.Other events should be suppressed in the report.

I'm facing a problem to design the report.Pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a grouping of employee with all of that employee's swipes below that, you could do a Min and Max of the time field at the employee level. Do a grouping of day above employee to make it just the records for that day.

For the lunch break, you could do a grouping on a formula which filters swipe times which are greater than 12:45 but less than 12:15, then just min and max on these within that grouping.